# How to read a single char from a word or phrase the user inputs

Tags: java, input, console

first question on here. Did some research already, but no luck. I think I have mostly everything correctly in my code, but I can't get it to work. It needs to read a single character from a string or phrase the user also inputs and then print out how many times it found it. I am a beginner in java and any help is greatly appreciated!! Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountCharacters{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            int timesFound;
            String stringSearched, characterSearched;

            System.out.printf("Enter a character for which to search: ");
            characterSearched = input.next();       
            System.out.printf("Enter the string to search: \n");
            stringSearched = input.nextLine();


            int numberOfCharacters = stringSearched.length();
            timesFound = 0;



            for (int x = 0; x < numberOfCharacters; x++)
            {
                char charSearched = characterSearched.charAt(0);

                if ( charSearched == stringSearched.charAt(x))
                    timesFound++;

                System.out.printf("\nThere are %d occurrences of \'%s\' in \"%s\"",
                        timesFound, characterSearched, stringSearched);
            }

   }    
}
```

Comment: Looks pretty good. Move the printout out of the loop

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the for-loop. Is it doing what you wanted to do? I think there is too much code in it. Here is how I would have done your task

- Read two times from `System.in` and assign the input to `characterSearched` respectively `stringSearched`
- Initialize a counter like  you did it with `timesFound`

  ```
  int timesFound = 0;
  ```
- Get the first character from `characterSearched`

  ```
  char charSearched = characterSearched.charAt(0);
  ```
- Loop over the string `stringSearched` and count

  ```
   for (int x = 0; x < stringSearched.length(); x++){
          if (charSearched == stringSearched.charAt(x))
              timesFound++;
      }
  ```
- Print the result

  ```
  System.out.printf("\nThere are %d occurrences of \'%s\' in \"%s\"",
                  timesFound, characterSearched, stringSearched);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Please comment out this line in your code:

```
// stringSearched = input.nextLine();
```

And replace with the following 2 lines.

```
input.nextLine();
stringSearched = input.next();
```

`nextLine()` sets the position to the beginning of the next line. 
So you would need another `input.next()`.

This is my first answer on this forum.
So pardon any etiquette mistakes I may have made.